# How to fix "Empty role name in AccessRuleSerializer." in SxA

Tags: sxa

Did anyone ever had this error message in a SxA Site:

```
Empty role name in AccessRuleSerialize?
```

We removed all security roles from the tenant and site items but still get this error. It appears only on the CD instance.

Any hint where to look at would be great!

Comment: We will need a bit more information. To start with: when and how do you see this error?

Comment: It happens when it redirects to a login page, but also in the logs, right before this happens: <br />
HttpModule is being initialized

Comment: And why does it redirect if you have no security set? Just a though: the error indicates a role with an empty name..  did you verify that you don't have that? (in the db)

Comment: I've removed all roles, for test purposes. To make sure, the assigned role is not the issue there. Now I also checked the roles table in core db for an emtpy role name, but there is none.

Comment: @Gatogordo: do you know where I can find the source code, maybe I can understand what and when this is checked